# Q: load new PHP variables values without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, backend

I have wonder how to load or refresh PHP variables after assigning them example:

```
<?PHP 
if(isset($_POST['rnd])){$post = $_POST['rnd'];}
?>

<input name='rnd' value='hey'> //insert any value
<?PHP if(isset($post)){?>
<div><h1><?PHP echo $post ?></h1></div><?PHP }?>
```

but if I do that I have to refresh the page to load the new value,
so what I'm looking for how to load the new value without refresh the page,
I searched the entire internet and did not find a helpful result,
no matter what is the language,
so anything will be helpful.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  If "the value" comes from an input element on the page then you already *have* the value, why do you need to use PHP at all?  It sounds like you're just looking for JavaScript, which you tagged in the question so you already know it exists...

Comment: If you're just asking how to interact with server-side code without refreshing the page then the technology you're looking for is "AJAX".

Comment: so let me clear this for you, after you post values ​​into PHP the values ​​will not change until you refresh the page, and I need PHP for backend purpose, not frontend, I tagged js because its frontend, to print those values ​​I have to access the frontend to reload the elements who have the new values, I hope I didn't mess it up.

Comment: @David thanks a lot for helping me, excuse me for taking up you time

Comment: I searched for it and it`s what was looking for thanks a lot you helped me and saved me a headache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a little vague. The answer depends on what you are trying to achieve and/or build.

1. Is your form action set to current page or PHP_SELF
2. Depending on what it is you are building you can create custom functions
3. If all else fails check the documentation. Should not have a
   problem displaying user input data on form submission.
4. Also, as was previously stated you could use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

special thanks to @David for the answer,
so the answer is ajax you can search for it and get in the deep of it.